# Cross-platform iteration of Unicode string (counting Graphemes using ICU)

Tags: c++, unicode, cross-platform, icu

I want to iterate *each character* of a Unicode string, *treating each surrogate pair and combining character sequence as a single unit* (one grapheme).

### Example

The text "नमस्ते" is comprised of the code points: `U+0928, U+092E, U+0938, U+094D, U+0924, U+0947`, of which, `U+0938` and `U+0947` are *combining marks*.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string s = "नमस्ते";

    Console.WriteLine(s.Length); // Ouptuts "6"

    var l = 0;
    var e = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
    while(e.MoveNext()) l++;
    Console.WriteLine(l); // Outputs "4"
}
```

So there we have it in .NET. We also have Win32's `CharNextW()`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t * s = L"नमस्ते";

    std::cout << std::wstring(s).length() << std::endl; // Gives "6"

    int l = 0;
    while(CharNextW(s) != s)
    {
        s = CharNextW(s);
        ++l;
    }

    std::cout << l << std::endl; // Gives "4"

    return 0;
}
```

### Question

Both ways I know of are specific to Microsoft. Are there **portable** ways to do it?

- I heard about ICU but I couldn't find something related quickly (`UnicodeString(s).length()` still gives 6). Would be an acceptable answer to point to the related function/module in ICU.
- C++ doesn't have a notion of Unicode, so a lightweight cross-platform library for dealing with these issues would make an acceptable answer.

### Edit: Correct answer using ICU

@McDowell gave the hint to use `BreakIterator` from ICU, which I think can be regarded as the de-facto cross-platform standard to deal with Unicode. Here's an example code to demonstrate its use (since examples are  **surprisingly** rare):

```
#include <unicode/schriter.h>
#include <unicode/brkiter.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    const UnicodeString str(L"नमस्ते");

    {
        // StringCharacterIterator doesn't seem to recognize graphemes
        StringCharacterIterator iter(str);
        int count = 0;
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            ++count;
            iter.next();
        }
        std::cout << count << std::endl; // Gives "6"
    }

    {
        // BreakIterator works!!
        UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
        std::unique_ptr<BreakIterator> iter(
            BreakIterator::createCharacterInstance(Locale::getDefault(), err));
        assert(U_SUCCESS(err));
        iter->setText(str);

        int count = 0;
        while(iter->next() != BreakIterator::DONE) ++count;
        std::cout << count << std::endl; // Gives "4"
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your title should read: "Cross Platform iteration of UTF-16 string"

Comment: @Chris: the problem is not specific to UTF-16, though, so it's more like "unicode non-utf32" :)

Comment: surrogate pairs are a utf-16 artifact. utf-8 just codes the final codepoint.

Comment: This question involves combining marks.  This feature allows text to contain composite glyphs in more than one natural way.  Text may contain characters with accents can represent those graphemes in terms of an unaccented character followed by a combining mark that adds the accent to the previous character, or by a single codepoint, if there is one, for the accented character.  This is totally different from surrogates in UTF-16, combining marks apply equally to all unicode encodings.

Comment: ICU's CharacterIterator, I think.  Like StringCharacterIterator.

Comment: (Ugh "comprised of". http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comprise#Verb)

Comment: `UnicodeString(s).length()` returns 6 because the string consist of six 16-bit code units.

Comment: `const UnicodeString str(L"नमस्ते")` will probably only work when `UChar` is `wchar_t`.

Comment: Please note: starting in C++11, you should favor `u"..."` strings over `L"..."` strings: `const UnicodeString str(u"नमस्ते")`

Comment: ICU's `StringCharacterIterator` can operate on [either code points or code units](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1ForwardCharacterIterator.html#details). _Code points_ are the Unicode characters whereas _code units_ are the storage units, i.e. bytes for utf-8.

You're using `StringCharacterIterator::next()` which returns the code unit, whereas [`StringCharacterIterator::next32()`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UCharCharacterIterator.html#ab4e41dae5d4ae832b473ebf09d98d48b) would return the Unicode code point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to use the ICU [BreakIterator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classBreakIterator.html) for this (the character instance assuming it is feature-equivalent to the Java version).

Answer (score 1):

Glib's [ustring](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glibmm/unstable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html) class gives you utf-8 strings, if using utf-8 is ok for you. It is designed to be similar to `std::string`. Since utf-8 is native for Linux, your task is quite easy:

```
int main()
{
    Glib::ustring s = L"नमस्ते";
    cout << s.size();
}
```

you can also iterate on string's characters as usual with `Glib::ustring::iterator`

Comment: This will eliminate surrogate pair issues, but doesn't deal with combining characters at all.

Comment: @aschepler: could you explain what you mean by combining characters please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character .  The example string here has 6 code points (no surrogate pairs are involved).  2 of them are combining characters, so the string has 4 graphemes.  @kizzx2 wants to iterate over those graphemes.

Answer (score 0):

ICU has a very old interface, Boost.Locale is much better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main()
{
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    auto string = "noël "sv;
    boost::locale::boundary::csegment_index map{
        boost::locale::boundary::character, std::begin(string),
        std::end(string), gen("")};
    for (const auto& i : map)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Text is from [here](https://mortoray.com/2013/11/27/the-string-type-is-broken/)