# How to count characters in a string encoded in an arbitrary character set

Tags: c++

Given a `std::string` containing text encoded in an arbitrary but known character set. What is the easiest way in C++ to count the characters? It should be able to handle things like combining characters and Unicode code points.

It would be nice to have something like:

```
std::string test = "éäöü";
std::cout << test.size("utf-8") << std::endl;
```

Unfortunately, life isn't always easy with C++. :)

For Unicode, I have seen that one can use the ICU library: [Cross-platform iteration of Unicode string (counting Graphemes using ICU)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579215/cross-platform-iteration-of-unicode-string-counting-graphemes-using-icu)

But is there a more general solution?

Comment: std::wstring comes to mind

Comment: std::wstring test = TEXT("éäöü"); std::cout << test.length();

Comment: @hanshenrik: Interesting. Haven't worked with `wchar_t` before. What would happen if you read the string from some input stream (like a file or stdin)?

Comment: In which way is ICU not general enough?

Comment: @MagnusHoff I thought ICU is only for Unicode?

Comment: Unicode is ... pretty general. What is it you cannot do with "merely" Unicode support? Keep in mind that ICU supports many encodings, including ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16 and Latin-1.

Comment: @MagnusHoff You may want to read my comment on the answer below

Comment: ICU does handle encodings other than UTF-8. I don't understand which scenario you are thinking of where ICU is not sufficient, please provide an example. However; I recommend that you instead specify in your API that the text must be UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it depends on the particular encoding. If you use UTF-8 (and I really don't see why you should not), you could use [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/).

It would appear they have a function to do just this:

```
::std::string test = "éäöü";
auto length = ::utf8::distance(test.begin(), test.end());
::std::cout << length << "\n"; // should print 4.
```

Comment: FYI: I am currently implementing a web service framework that has a feature to validate the length of submitted text. So the encoding depends on whatever the user wants to use. Most of them will use UTF-8 but it should also work with others.