# Using Unicode (UTF-8) in C++

Tags: linux, string, c++11, unicode, utf-8

Currently, I have to deal with Unicode in C++ 11 (Linux environment).
UTF-8 is used as default encoding.
Tasks that I need:

- Replace.
- Regex
- Iterate through a UTF-8 string. I don't know if using std::string and "for (character c : s)" will do what I want 'cause each character must be a unicode character. For example ế is one character, mão is a word contains 3 characters
- Substring.
- Concatenate substring with unicode characters or concatenate unicode characters.
- Length.
- Trim.
- Read and write files.

What library should I use to achieve the best result?

Thank you very much.
Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: C++ strings deal only in raw elements (`char` for `std::string`, `wchar_t` for `std::wstring`, `char16_t` for `std::u16string`, `char32_t` for `std::u32string`), they have no concept of character encodings, like UTF-8/16/32 (though `char16_t` is intended for UTF-16, and `char32_t` for UTF-32), which may use more than 1 element per single Unicode codepoint, depending on its value. I will say that a `for (character c : s)` loop WILL not handle Unicode characters outside the BMP for `std::string` or `std::u16string`. but it will for `std::u32string`, and `std::wstring` when `wchar_t` is 4 bytes.

Comment: For what you are asking, you really need a good Unicode-aware library. There are plenty of them available if you look around (don't ask here, asking for recommendations are off-topic).

Comment: Thank you very much.
I did my research before asking.
The 3 libs that I found are UTF8CPP, ICU:Unicode, Boost.
I don't know which is the best and is there any better out there?

Comment: "best" is subjective. Use whichever one(s) suit your needs. Use multiple ones, if you want.

Comment: Oh yeah. My bad. I should say "suit".
Thank you very much.

Comment: To input and output UTF-8 with the STL, you can `std::imbue` the `wcin` and `wcout` wide-character streams, and any files you use, with converter facets from `<codecvt>`. If you don’t need to work on individual characters, and are just passing strings through literally, you can just treat them as `char*`.

Comment: Windows needs a bit of extra magic: you must `_setmode()` to `_O_U8TEXT` and set the console code page to 65001.

Comment: While I answered, this is several questions asking to recommend a library, so StackOverflow is not necessarily where you’d want to ask this in the future.

Comment: Are you writing a text-processing application? Your requirements are a vast overkill for any but most demanding and full-featured text processors. And UTF-8 is not necessarily the most appropriate *internal* encoding for such applications (you if course need to read and write UTF-8 files but it's the easiest part of this business).

Comment: @n.m. I'm writing a text-preprocessor. Text from files must be pre-processed before feeding to my ML model. The encoding of input files is UTF-8. One of the task relates to Unicode character (must be checked character by character in a string).

Comment: "Unicode characters" are code points. What you describe is called user-perceived characters or [grapheme clusters](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries). Out of the three libraries you mention, only ICU is capable of this; but I'm not quite sure *why* you would need to consider grapheme clusters. What kind of pre-processing are you doing?

Comment: In some languages, a grapheme cluster is considered as a single character. Some normalization tasks (based-on language knowledges) require grapheme cluster iteration, grapheme clusters replacement, etc.

Comment: You may want to ask a separate question that describes these tasks in detail. It could be as simple as detecting combining characters in [NFD](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms), or more complicated. They probably go far beyond your initial scope of "using UTF-8".

Comment: Thank you. Already done simple tasks (include NFC). Only some tasks that must process grapheme clusters separately remain. I'm trying to use ICU:Unicode to achieve my goal. I hope it'll be okay.

Answer (score 2):

For the regex/replace/search functions, I’ve previously used PCRE.  This is designed to work with UTF-8 strings.  You might be able to work with STL regular expressions, but not in any portable way.  (Windows, in particular, does not support UTF-8 locales.)

Iterating through a UTF-8 string is even more complicated than you describe, if you need to support combining marks or the zero-width joiner! You write that `é` is one character, but it might be two Unicode codepoints: Latin small letter e + combining acute accent above.  If you simply want to iterate through codepoints, you might use `mbtowc()` or `std::codecvt::do_in` from the Standard Library.  If you need to iterate through graphemes, the most portable way to do that is with [ICU.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579215/cross-platform-iteration-of-unicode-string-counting-graphemes-using-icu)

Regular string concatenation should work, and the standard library has `mblen()` for length.  This isn’t completely portable, because the multibyte encoding does not have to be UTF-8 (although there is a standard set of conversion functions).