# Output all line graphemes to the console

Tags: c++, boost

How to do this in C++ using boost locale?
In one of the questions I found an example
[Cross-platform iteration of Unicode string (counting Graphemes using ICU)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579215/cross-platform-iteration-of-unicode-string-counting-graphemes-using-icu)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main()
{
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    auto string = "noël "sv;
    boost::locale::boundary::csegment_index map{
        boost::locale::boundary::character, std::begin(string),
        std::end(string), gen("")};
    for (const auto& i : map)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

This code turned out to be non-working.How can I fix it?
Error:

E0289   no instance of constructor "boost::locale::boundary::segment_index::segment_index [with BaseIterator=const char *]" matches the argument list

C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'boost::locale::boundary::segment_index<const char *>'

### [image]
[image]

Version of boost: 1.81.0, I use a pre-release version of the C++23 and C17 standard. Visual Studio. The boost is statically bonded. Icu is installed. File encoded utf8. I compile the project as release x64

Comment: What compiler / platform are you using? Also `non-working` is not description of problem!

Comment: In response to the error message: (finally complete! even though it is still in picture form...) it complains about initializer lists. You might help the compiler "get it" by changing to parentheses: `boost::locale::boundary::csegment_index map(boost::locale::boundary::character, std::begin(string), std::end(string), loc);`

Comment: Looks like an MSVC-specific problem, works just fine with gcc and clang. Replacing `iterator` arguments with `const char*` fixes the problem.

Comment: @sehe Replaced, the problem remains

Comment: @n.m. can you give me a code example?

Comment: [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dKssY1xxb)

Comment: @n.m. The program compiles and exits with code -1073740791

Comment: This is a different problem. The program works as is with gcc and clang on Linux. I cannot test running with msvc. I can only test compiling with msvc using godbolt.

Answer (score 1):

It does work for me with `gen("")` as well as `gen("en_US.utf8")`:

[image]

If it doesn't work for you, check that

- Your source file encoding (UTF8 is assumed here)
- Boost is built with ICU support
- your system supports UNICODE locales

---

Comment: Code does not compile in windows Visual Studio

Comment: @MaKeSter was that your original problem? Why don't you include the error message that you see, and the Boost/compiler versions that you use? "This code turned out to be non-working" is completely useless for troubleshooting.

Comment: Version of boost: 1.81.0, I use a pre-release version of the C++23 and C17 standard.

Comment: Error: E0289 no instance of constructor "boost::locale::boundary::segment_index<BaseIterator>::segment_index [with BaseIterator=const char *]" matches the argument list

Comment: @MaKeSter question details go in the question! Please use the edit button there

Comment: My crystal ball says you might be using wide-char literals. Consider trying `wcsegment_index`

Comment: With wcsegment_index the error persists.

Your source file encoding (UTF8 is assumed here) - yes, Boost is built with ICU support - how to check this?, your system supports UNICODE locales - how to check this?

Comment: Since you're on Windows, I assume UNICODE is supported. Regardless, we now finally know that you have a compilation error, so it's not relevant to the error. Checking about ICU could be done in many (platform specific) ways, or using https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/locale/doc/html/using_localization_backends.html or the `BOOST_LOCALE_WITH_ICU` define

Comment: Can't this be fixed? Do I have to switch to Linux?

Comment: We're still [finding the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440884/output-all-line-graphemes-to-the-console/76441802?noredirect=1#comment134791217_76440884)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is most probably handling encoding.

If you are using MSVC make sure, that:

- source file is encoded with UTF-8
- compler received `/utf-8` switch - to properly read source code and generate executable which for strings uses UTF-8
- locale is configured properly:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string_view>

#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(".utf-8")); // inform standard library that executable is using UTF-8 encoding
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("")); // use system locale on standard output

    boost::locale::generator gen;
    auto string = "noël "sv;
    boost::locale::boundary::csegment_index map{
        boost::locale::boundary::character, std::begin(string),
        std::end(string), gen(".utf-8")};
    for (const auto& i : map)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```