# How i do return one letter same size regardless of languages

Tags: c++, string, dynamic, wstring

I am beginer. i am studying Dynamic allocate in C++.

I want to get a certain string length back regardless of whether I enter Korean or English.
So I'm using wstring. However, just as wstring.length() or wstring.size() continues to be a Multibyte system, Korean returns 2 bytes and English 1 byte
How i do return one letter same size regardless of languages.

```
void ex_03() {
    std::wcout << endl<< "Your Input : " << endl;
    wstring inputval;
    std::wcin >> inputval;
    int slength = inputval.size();

    wchar_t* p = new wchar_t[slength];

    int cnt = 0;
    for (wchar_t a : inputval) {
        p[cnt] = a;
        cnt++;
    }

    std::wcout << endl << "your Input length : " << slength << endl << "String is : " << p;
    
    delete[] p;
}
```

i think to use wstring.. but it is strange..

Comment: C++ is doesn't do UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding. Side note : Why use `wchar_t* p = new wchar_t[slength];` when you can use std::wstring?

Comment: `wchar_t* p = new wchar_t[slength];` have one major issue: It's not a null-.terminated string, so can't be used as such (which you do when you try to print it).

Comment: And what is your actual problem that this code is supposed to solve? Why do you need to copy the input to a character array?

Comment: i am begginer. i am solving exercise example.

"Write a program that receives a string as input, and then stores it in dynamically allocated memory using the new operator. The output of the program should be the length of the string and the string itself."

Comment: when i use std::wstring too, it is like multibyte string

Comment: @Nothing If not mentioned, regard the input as English-only

Comment: @all I solved problems! Thanks
#include <locale>
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
i add upside code. So they works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your task is:

> Write a program that receives a string as input, and then stores it in dynamically allocated memory using the new operator. The output of the program should be the length of the string and the string itself.

... it's almost certainly not required to handle Unicode strings.
You don't even need to use `std::wcout` and `std::wcin`; the task probably gives you English input only and `std::string` would be enough.

See also [Getting the actual length of a UTF-8 encoded std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4063146/5740428) for count code points in UTF-8 strings. Assuming your `std::cin` gives you UTF-8 strings (it almost certainly does), you could use this approach.

However, even counting code points in UTF-8 strings isn't enough because there are graphemes which consist of multiple code points, such as `é` (`U+00E9`, Latin Small Letter E with Acute) which can also be formed by a combining acute accent (`U+0301`) with base letter `e` (`U+0065`).

Furthermore, Devanagari Letter Qa `क़` (`U+0958`) is also represented by:

- Devanagari Letter Ka (`U+0915`)
- Devanagari Sign Nukta (`U+093C`)

There are numerous other examples. The point is that getting the grapheme-length of a string is extremely complicated and likely not what the task requires of you. See also [Cross-platform iteration of Unicode string (counting Graphemes using ICU)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4579215/5740428)

Comment: Happy, I will refer your link and comment. I think that the intention of this exercise is to make me googling.

Comment: I solved problems 
#include <locale> 

setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); 

So they works properly.