# Unicode encoding for filesystem in Mac OS X not correct in Python?

Tags: python, macos, unicode, file-io, filesystems

Having a bit of struggle with Unicode file names in OS X and Python. I am trying to use filenames as input for a regular expression later in the code, but the encoding used in the filenames seem to be different from what sys.getfilesystemencoding() tells me. Take the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import sys,os
print sys.getfilesystemencoding()

p = u'/temp/s/'
s = u'åäö'
print 's', [ord(c) for c in s], s
s2 = s.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print 's2', [ord(c) for c in s2], s2
os.mkdir(p+s)
for d in os.listdir(p):
  print 'dir', [ord(c) for c in d], d
```

It outputs the following:

```
utf-8
s [229, 228, 246] åäö
s2 [195, 165, 195, 164, 195, 182] åäö
dir [97, 778, 97, 776, 111, 776] åäö
```

So, file system encoding is utf-8, but when I encode my filename åäö using that, it will not be the same as if I create a dir name with the same string. I expect that when I use my string åäö to create a dir, and read it's name back, it should use the same codes as if I applied the encoding directly.

If we look at the code points 97, 778, 97, 776, 111, 776, it's basically ASCII characters with added diacritic, e.g. o + ¨ = ö, which makes it two characters, not one. How can I avoid this discrepancy, is there an encoding scheme in Python that matches this behaviour by OS X, and why is not getfilesystemencoding() giving me the right result?

Or have I messed up?

Comment: The problem can be solved for those specific characters, by doing the following regexp on filename strings to get them into diacritic-less unicode:`m_aa = re.compile(ur"a\u0308",re.I), m_ae = re.compile(ur"a\u030a",re.I), m_oe = re.compile(ur"o\u0308",re.I)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

MacOS X uses a special kind of decomposed UTF-8 to store filenames. If you need to e.g. read in filenames and write them to a "normal" UTF-8 file, you must normalize them :

```
filename = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', unicode(filename, 'utf-8')).encode('utf-8')
```

from here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120423075412/http://boodebr.org/main/python/all-about-python-and-unicode

Comment: Ran into this problem with node.js the npm package `unorm` has a really nice interface for this.

Answer (score 23):

`getfilesystemencoding()` is giving you the correct response (the *encoding*), but it does not tell you the [unicode normalisation form](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

In particular, the HFS+ filesystem uses UTF-8 encoding, and a normalisation form close to "D" (which requires composed characters like `ö` to be decomposed into `o¨`). HFS+ is also tied to the normalisation form as it existed in Unicode version 3.2—as detailed in Apple's [documentation for the HFS+ format](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties).

Python's [`unicodedata.normalize`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) method converts between forms, and if you prefix the call with the `ucd_3_2_0` object, you can constrain it to Unicode version 3.2:

```
filename = unicodedata.ucd_3_2_0.normalize('NFC', unicode(filename, 'utf-8')).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer, wish I could upvote and accept both answers!

Comment: Actually, it’s not quite NFD, but it’s close.

Comment: If HFS+ stores filenames in decomposed form, wouldn't you use `normalise('NFD'...)` to match the HFS+ encoding?