# How can I canonicalize diacritic string representation between .NET and Mono OSX?

Tags: .net, macos, unicode, mono, diacritics

I have a cross platform application using .NET for Windows and Mono for Mac / OSX.

My application deals with filenames and writes serialized data structures to disk which contain filenames as Strings.  Some of these filenames have international characters like accents.

When I copy my data files which were created on Windows (NTFS) to Mac, I have some problems with the files whose names have these international accent characters.

The filenames which were read from NTFS and serialized by .NET contain a single character for the accented letter, but when I read the filename from the filesystem using Mono on OSX, I get the two character representation which doesn't match the serialized representation.  I need to maintain consistency between the serialized filenames and the actual filesystem on both Windows and Mac.

For example, the letter é was gotten from a filename using .NET on Windows and was serialized as a single character with integer value 233.  On OSX, I use Mono to read the filename of the copied file and that letter is represented with two characters of integer values 101 and 769, which represent the letter and accent as distinct characters.  The problem is that this representation does not match the serialized representation that was written on Windows.

I need to find some way to enforce consistency - either in the serialized data structures containing the filenames, or in the filenames themselves.

Is there some way in .NET/Mono to canonicalize these different string representations?  I looked at the Normalize() method, but I don't think that it does what I want.  Either that or I am not understanding the documentation.

Can NTFS also store filenames with the two character representation of accented letters?  If so, will it treat the two representations as being distinct?  I might prefer to do the canonicalization on the actual filenames themselves.

My thanks in advance!

Comment: This is in fact what String.Normalize() does.

Comment: String.Normalize() solved a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that Windows and Mac OS X use different systems for encoding characters in filenames.

According to [the first answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as), NTFS stores filenames using UTF-16. However, according to [the second answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757843/unicode-encoding-for-filesystem-in-mac-os-x-not-correct-in-python), Mac OS X stores filenames using UTF-8 via normalization form D, in which the glyph "é" is "canonically decomposed" into "e" (101) and the combining acute accent mark "´" (769).

So I fear that unless you restrict your filenames to plain ASCII, they're simply going to have different representations on the two operating systems.

Comment: Incidentally, I thought I knew a lot about Unicode, but only learned about this "canonical decomposition" business when looking into answering this question. Live and learn!

Answer (score 0):

Here to celebrate this topic's 10 years old - still relevant today (with APFS on Catalina, Monterey, Ventura etc.)-

I had to write a script that compares two indexes (after a backup, to make sure all files and folders are well copied).

Source is macOS (APFS), destination is on a SMB server (NTFS I guess?).
Script basically is `find $SRC >$indexSRC`, `find $DST >$indexDST`, and `comm $indexSRC $indexDST`.

Because of the issue discussed here, file names with diacritics would not match between SRC and DST.
For exemple 'ü':

- On source, they are of type `ü ** \n`.
- On dest (smb share), they are of type `u \n` followed by  `̈ ** \n`.

The workaround was to convert indexDST to mac format:

```
iconv -f UTF-8-MAC "$indexDST" > "$indexDSTconverted"
```

After that, `comm indexSRC indexDSTconverted` shows the expected result.