# How do I get a list of all files in unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I need to get a list of files in a directory, where the filenames have to be unicode.

The following code gives me a list of files.

```
files = [ f for f in listdir(filedirectory) if isfile(join(filedirectory,f)) ]
for fi in files:
    print(fi)
    print(type(fi))
```

Result:

```
AT10_nachmittags.JPG
<type 'str'>
AT11_nachmittags.JPG
<type 'str'>
AT12_nachmittags.JPG
<type 'str'>
AT2_morgens2.JPG
<type 'str'>
AT3_morgens.JPG
<type 'str'>
AT_morgens.JPG
<type 'str'>
Bühne.JPG
<type 'str'>
Bühnenauftritt.JPG
<type 'str'>
```

The problem is that these are not unicode. I need them to be unicode so I can write them in a file because they include german "umlaute" unicode symbols.

I'm working on Mac OS X 10.10.4 with python 2.7.6

Comment: OS and Python version would be useful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9758014/2372812 Looks relevant.

Comment: If you intend to work with Unicode, I cannot stress enough how much you should move to Python 3.

Comment: The Unicode is escaped currently.

Answer (score 3):

Try to execute listdir with filedirectory as unicode string argument. E.g. filedirectory = u'/some/dir'

From documentation:

> os.listdir(path) Return a list containing the names of the entries in
>   the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does
>   not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present
>   in the directory.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.
>
> **> Changed in version 2.3: On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if path is a
>   Unicode object, the result will be a list of Unicode objects.
>   Undecodable filenames will still be returned as string objects.**

Comment: try to switch to Python 3

Comment: @Luke I’m returning OS X with python 2.7.10 and it returns Unicode strings for me.

Comment: @Luke: check again. Are you sure that `isinstance(filedirectory, unicode)` is true just before you pass `filedirectory` to `os.listdir()`?

Comment: @svfat: undecodable names are unlikely on OSX where utf-8 is enforced for filenames. And all names in the question are decodable anyway.