# Unicode string not being detected in data structure

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

Using python 2, I'm unable to detect if my unicode string is detected in a list, set, or dictionary.

For example
I'm generating the list by iterating through file names

```
res = []
for root, dir, file in os.walk('./'):
    for name in file:
        res.append(name.replace('/', '_'))
```

One of the file's name is `Município`

When I print the item out I get `Munici\xcc\x81pio`. That's not an issue, but when I try to check if `Município` is in the list, it returns false. I check if both are unicode and they are.

Comment: Is this windows? What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` say?

Comment: OSX. It prints out `utf-8`

Comment: What does `print repr(name)` show? It seems like that file name wasn't encoded properly when it was created.

Comment: Ah, I get `Munici\xcc\x81pio`

Comment: You don't get `'Munici\xcc\x81pio'`? That's strange. When you simply print a string it does encoding which can mask the real problem. `repr` can be more definitive.

Comment: Oh i do. forgot the quotes! My bad.

Comment: `name.decode('utf-8') == u"Município"` should work, but you may need to add `# coding=utf-8` to the top of your script (second line, if you use a shebang).

Comment: Watch out for different Unicode normalisation forms: [Unicode encoding for filesystem in Mac OS X not correct in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757843/unicode-encoding-for-filesystem-in-mac-os-x-not-correct-in-python)

Comment: Thank you both! @roeland that link helped! Did not know OSX differently encodes.