# Safari encodes strings with accent marks differently than Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, utf-8, safari

The length of the string `Pépé` is 6 characters in Chrome, but it is 4 characters in Safari. To determine this, I open up the consoles in both the browsers and enter the following code:

```
"Pépé".length
```

This difference is giving me trouble on the server side.

I am using jQuery.$ajax to send a POST request with data containing the string `Pépé`. When that data reaches the server, it is treating the values differently. I am able to retrieve the data when I am in Chrome but not when I am in Safari.

Inside of the ajax request, I am setting the parameter, `contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8`.

On the server side, it looks like `P√©p√©` when doing the POST request from Safari and `PeÃÅpeÃÅ` when doing the POST request from Chrome.

Any clue why there is a difference between browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into different "normalizations" as there are different ways those accents etc. could be mushed into UTF-8.

There is a really nice discussion here in the answers:

[What is normalized UTF-8 all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931204/what-is-normalized-utf-8-all-about)

That answer is in the PHP section of Stack Overflow, Java has similar ways of manipulating UTF-8 too.  The browsers are probably going to send UTF-8 how they are going to send it.  On the server side you probably need to just normalize all your data to NFD or NFC.

I would just force everything to NFC server side.  If you are in Java something like this can do it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html

Edit:
in all cases byte length and character length will depend on the normalization, as will strict comparisons -- regardless of programming language.