# Javascript encodeURI() vs. PHP rawurldecode() and special characters

Tags: javascript, php, url, urlencode, url-encoding

Encoding a string with German umlauts like ä,ü,ö,ß with Javascript **encodeURI()** causes a weird bug after decoding it in PHP with **rawurldecode()**. Although the string seems to be correctly decoded it isn't. See below example screenshots from my IDE

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also the **strlen()** of the - with rawurldecode() - decoded string gives more characters than it really has!

Problems occur when I need to process the decoded string, for example if I want to replace the German characters ä,ü,ö with ae, ue and oe. This can be seen in the example provided [here](http://3v4l.org/T1g1O).

I have also made an [PHP fiddle](http://3v4l.org/T1g1O) where this whole weirdness can be seen.

What I've tried so far:
- utf8_decode
- iconv
- and also first two suggestions from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#101401)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) issue and it looks like your IDE doesnt handle multibyte strings very well.

In unicode you can represent Ü with either:

- the single unicode codepoint (U+00DC) or %C3%9C in utf8
- or use a capital U (U+0055) with a modifier (U+0308) or %55%CC%88 in utf8

Your GWT string uses the latter method called NFD while your one from PHP uses the first method called NFC.  That's why your GWT string is 3 characters longer even though they are both valid encodings of logically identical unicode strings.  Your problem is that they are not identical byte for byte in PHP.

More details about [utf-8 normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931204/what-is-normalized-utf-8-all-about/7934397#7934397).

If you want to do preg replacements on the strings you need to normalise them to the same form first.  From your example I can see your IDE is using NFC since it's the PHP string that works.  So I suggest normalising to NFC form in PHP (the default), then doing the preg_replace.

http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php

```
function cleanImageName($name)
{
    $name = Normalizer::normalize( $name, Normalizer::FORM_C );
        $clean = preg_replace(
```

Otherwise you have to do something [like this](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php#Hcom92592) which is based on [this article](http://ahinea.com/en/tech/accented-translate.html).