# Does mbstring normalize utf-8 strings?

Tags: php, utf-8, normalization, mbstring

I noticed that [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) always returns valid utf-8, which is great for cleaning up user input, but I wonder whether it will return a normalized form of utf-8 or whether I would have to do that manually after with the [`\Normalizer`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) class?

Comment: See also [what is normalized UTF-8 all about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931204/what-is-normalized-utf-8-all-about)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mbstring/mbstring.c#L3134-L3217), `mb_convert_encoding` does not appear to normalize. It appears to convert between encodings then to substitute illegal characters, and that is all.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea to look at the source although I probably wouldn't have felt confident in decrypting it...