# How can I convert this UTF-8 string to plain text in javascript and how can a normal user write it in a textarea

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

A text saved in our database was causing problems. After some investigation, I found out that the text was the following:

```
var text = '"\ud835\ude45\ud835\ude6a\ud835\ude68\ud835\ude69\ud835\ude5e\ud835\ude5b\ud835\ude5e\ud835\ude66\ud835\ude6a\ud835\ude5a \ud835\ude68\ud835\ude6a\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude68 \ud835\ude67\ud835\ude5a\ud835\ude68\ud835\ude65\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude68\ud835\ude69\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude68 \ud835\ude5e\ud835\ude63\ud835\ude59\ud835\ude5e\ud835\ude58\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude63\ud835\ude59\ud835\ude64 \ud835\ude64\ud835\ude68 \ud835\ude58\ud835\ude56\u0301\ud835\ude61\ud835\ude58\ud835\ude6a\ud835\ude61\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude68 \ud835\ude67\ud835\ude5a\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude61\ud835\ude5e\ud835\ude6f\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude59\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude68 \ud835\ude5a \ud835\ude5b\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude69\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude5c\ud835\ude67\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude5b\ud835\ude5a \ud835\ude69\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude59\ud835\ude64 \ud835\ude64 \ud835\ude65\ud835\ude67\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude58\ud835\ude5a\ud835\ude68\ud835\ude68\ud835\ude64 \ud835\ude65\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude67\ud835\ude56 \ud835\ude65\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude63\ud835\ude69\ud835\ude6a\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude67 \ud835\ude63\ud835\ude56 \ud835\ude66\ud835\ude6a\ud835\ude5a\ud835\ude68\ud835\ude69\ud835\ude56\u0303\ud835\ude64. \ud835\ude47\ud835\ude5a\ud835\ude62\ud835\ude57\ud835\ude67\ud835\ude5a-\ud835\ude68\ud835\ude5a \ud835\ude59\ud835\ude5a \ud835\ude56\ud835\ude63\ud835\ude5a\ud835\ude6d\ud835\ude56\ud835\ude67 \ud835\ude68\ud835\ude6a\ud835\ude56 \ud835\ude5b\ud835\ude64\ud835\ude69\ud835\ude64"';
```

I know that it can be read with decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse(text)), which outputs:

```
"     ́          ̃. -    "
```

I have two questions: how can I convert that text to

```
"Justifique suas respostas indicando os cálculos realizados e fotografe todo o processo para pontuar na questão. Lembre-se de anexar sua foto"
```

And what is the most probable way that it was written in a textarea and saved in my DB?

Please notice that:

```
'' === 'Justifique'  // returns false
```

Comment: `decodeURIComponent()` has nothing to do with dealing with character set issues.

Comment: What DB are you using? What format is it currently at?

Comment: We are using postgres, but I think it has no relation with the problem. The DB just saved what was written by a user at the frontend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the point of String.normalize()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013552/whats-the-point-of-string-normalize) Try `.normalize('NFKC')` or `.normalize('NFKD')`.

Comment: Yes, it answers in part:
''.normalize('NFKC') === 'Justifique'  returns true.

Only the second question left to answer.

Comment: NFKD is enough in this case.
"NFC": Canonical Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition.
"NFD": Canonical Decomposition.
"NFKC": Compatibility Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition.
"NFKD": Compatibility Decomposition.