# Byte arrays and strings in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
        byte arr[] = new byte[] {56, 99, 87, 77, 73, 90, 105, -23, -52, -85, -9, -55, -115, 11, -127, -127};
        String s= new String(arr);
        Arrays.equals(arr, s.getBytes()));  // returns false
```

Why are the arrays not equal?
I would expect `getBytes()` to return the original byte array.

Comment: I suggest inspecting the arrays manually. What do you get if you print `s.getBytes()`? Is it the same as the original `arr`?

Comment: `56 99 87 77 73 90 105 -23 -52 -85 -9 -55 -115 11 -127 -127`
`56 99 87 77 73 90 105 -23 -52 -85 -9 -55 -115 11 63 63`

Comment: Are negative bytes valid when using the default character encoding on your system?

Comment: Negative values are not really relevant. Character encodings don't care. The result will depend on what character encoding is used. Running it with `-Dfile.encoding=Latin1` will 'work'

Comment: Its all about which charset these characters represented by these negative numbers belong to. If you know it, it will work

Comment: As will GB18030 GBK IBM00858 IBM437 IBM775 IBM850 IBM852 IBM855 IBM857 IBM862 IBM866 ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-13 ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-16 ISO-8859-2 ISO-8859-3 ISO-8859-4 ISO-8859-5 ISO-8859-7 ISO-8859-9 KOI8-R KOI8-U windows-1251 x-IBM737 x-iso-8859-11

Comment: Both `new String(bytes[])` and `getBytes()` use the `Charset.defaultCharset()`

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao *If you know it, it will work* Knowing *alone* won't help you. You need to set that `file.encoding` in the system or use the correct argument to `getBytes`

Comment: Btw. Thanks, this makes a great java puzzler ;)

Comment: Of course, starting in JDK 18 UTF-8 is going to be the [default character set](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400), so the results will also depend on what Java version you are using. Basically, never use the `new String(byte[])` or `getBytes()` methods; always use the overloads that let you specify the charset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your `Charset.defaultCharset()`. That determines how the bytes are interpreted. Probably the negative values are a non-canonical way of representing codepoints.

(see this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7934397/461499)

Re-interpreting the `getBytes()` to a `String` will then be the canonical way and will return `true`

```
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset()); //UTF-8 here :)

    byte arr[] = new byte[] {56, 99, 87, 77, 73, 90, 105, -23, -52, -85, -9, -55, -115, 11, -127, -127};
    String s= new String(arr);
    System.out.println(s);
    // [56, 99, 87, 77, 73, 90, 105, -17, -65, -67, -52, -85, -17, -65, -67, -55, -115, 11, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67]

    byte arr2[] = new byte[] {56, 99, 87, 77, 73, 90, 105, -17, -65, -67, -52, -85, -17, -65, -67, -55, -115, 11, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes()));  
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arr, s.getBytes()));  // returns false

    String s2= new String(arr2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s2.getBytes()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arr2, s2.getBytes()));  // returns true
```

Comment: *Probably the negative values are a non-canonical way of representing codepoints.* Well as I mentioned above, negativity of values is not really relevant as such. An eight-bit character encoding is by definition going to have negative values as `byte` is signed in Java

Comment: That is true, it does not have to do with them being negative *directly*. However, in UTF-8, these specific values (with the bits starting with 1...) have specific meaning.

Comment: @RobAudenaerde the reason why the later comparison prints true is that you have manually replaced the non existing utf-8 byte elements or sequence of elements with the question mark character which is a valid utf-8 character and is represented by the byte sequense `-17, -65, -67`

Comment: I did not do anything with String-output, I just fiddled the byte array. The non-existing input is converted by the `Charset` to a valid sequence.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to think that bytes and characters are interchangeable.

They simply are not.

To turn characters into bytes, you 'encode' the characters using a 'charset encoding'. To turn bytes back into characters, you decode them using a 'charset encoding'. **There is no such thing as converting one to the other *without* a charset encoding**.

The transition bytes->chars->bytes is only 'perfect' (guaranteed to always give you the same byte array back) for a select few encoding systems. **Most encoding systems do not have this property**. An encoding system that does, is ISO-8859-1. However, the *2 most common encodings do not have this property*: Neither UTF-8 nor US-ASCII gets the job done.

The methods you use here (both `str.getBytes` as well as `new String(byteArr)`) use the 'platform default encoding'. Starting with JDK18, that's guaranteed to be UTF-8 (thus guaranteeing that this will not work properly), and before that, it's whatever your system's default encoding is, which we don't know.

US-ASCII doesn't work because US_ASCII only defines a subset of all bytes as 'valid': 0-126. Most of your bytes (all of them with a minus sign) aren't valid ASCII.

UTF-8 doesn't work because not all byte sequences are valid UTF-8. In other words, there are sequences of bytes that simply cannot be produced with UTF_8.

More to the point though, the entire principle is just broken. Even if you know it's ISO-8859-1, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? You may be able to translate an arbitrary byte array into ISO-8859-1 and back again without losing anything, but what point does this serve? You can easily produce strings that cause havoc, with NUL characters, tabs, backspaces, 'bell' sounds, and other bizarreness. It's a string you'd never ever want to print. Which asks the question: Why do you want one, then?

There really is only one sensible answer to that question, and that is: I wish to transport these bytes through a medium that only supports strings. For example, I have some raw bytes, and I want to put them in an email, or in a form field for a jira ticket or something silly like that, and an attachment is for some reason not an option in this. Or I want to stuff it into a URL (`https://www.foo.bar/?q=raw-bytes-here`).

There are 2 answers to doing that, and neither involve `new String(byteArr)`:

### Nibbles

Any raw byte can trivially be turned into hexadecimal representation: 255 (or -1, in signed byte form, it's the same thing) turns into `FF`. 1 turns into 01 - all bytes are always exactly 2 characters in length. You can use:

```java
byte f = -1;
String nibbled = String.format("%02X", (int) f);
System.out.println(nibbled); // prints 'FF'
```

The individual letter/digit (0-9A-F. Technically that's just a digit, in hexadecimal, where A-F are also digits) is called a 'nibble' (because it's half a byte, see. Boy, the 60s when these terms were invented were a hoot weren't they).

This is somewhat inefficient; a byte array of X bytes turns into a string of 2*X characters (and each character may well take 2 bytes, e.g. if it is UTF-16 encoded, for a total of 25% efficiency, ouch). But it is trivially readable and common. It's great for short (sub 500 or so bytes) byte arrays.

Another advantage is that you can eyeball the string and know what the data is, if you can read hexadecimal and, if signed is relevant, 2's complement, which is not too difficult.

### Base64

Base64 is a simple encoding scheme that defines 64 'safe' characters that you know will safely 'survive' without getting mangled or misinterpreted. That gives you 6 bits of data per character. Bytes are 8, so, you can 'stuff' 3 bytes into 4 characters this way; for example a 900 byte array turns into 1200 characters.

Java has [base64 encoding/decoding built in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

```java
byte arr[] = new byte[] {56, 99, 87, 77, 73, 90, 105, -23, -52, -85, -9, -55, -115, 11, -127, -127};
String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arr);
// s is all ASCII chars and safe to include just about everywhere.
// URL parameter, emails, web forms, you name it.
byte[] arr2 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
Arrays.equals(arr, arr2); // true, guaranteed.
```

Base64 is slightly more complicated, and you can no longer eyeball a base64 string and just see the bytes matrix-style. But it is more efficient than nibble form: 75% efficiency (or 37.5% if the underlying characters take 2 bytes per char, i.e. with UTF-16).

Answer (score 1):

The following constructor will read the `byte` array and decode it and  according to the default charset.

```
new String(arr);
```

So when you do

```
String s= new String(arr);
 s.getBytes()
```

the `bytes()` returns the array again as was previously decoded according to the default charset.

If you inspect with debugger you can see how the `new String(byte [])` method works for `UTF-8` default charSet. You will see that the byte `{-127}` is decoded into `{-17, -65, -67}` because `-127` as byte is not valid for `Utf-8`. So `{-127}` is decoded into `{-17, -65, -67}` because this represents the Replacement character of `Utf-8` -> �.

Actually any element or sequence of elements of `byte` array that can't be matched as a valid `Utf-8` character when this is the default charset, it is then converted into `{-17, -65, -67}` which is the representation for the �.

In your example the following bytes `{-9, -127, -23}` are non valid for `Utf-8` charset. So the previous array of the 3 elements is converted into ��� which in bytes array again is represented from `{-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67}`

So by removing the non valid `Utf-8` bytes `-9` , `-127`, `-23` from your example will return true for default charset `Utf-8` as all of your remaining bytes can be decoded by `Utf-8`

```
        byte arr[] = new byte[] {56, 99, 87, 77, 73, 90, 105, -52, -85, -55, -115, 11};
        String s= new String(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arr, s.getBytes())); //prints true
```

This indicates that when you create a `String` from a `byte` array the original `byte` array will be decoded into a new `byte` array according to the charset. So you can't expect with `string.getBytes()` to retrieve the original `byte` array if some of the provided byte elements are non valid according to the related charset.

**So in the end we can sum up into the following:**

Your code will always return true, as far as all  provided elements/sequence of elements in your byte array  can be decoded by the underlying charset that JVM uses when it executes your code.
If any of those elements or sequence of elements is unknown to the relative charset then it will be decoded into some failing characters which will be later represented by some other byte element or sequence of byte elements which represent those special characters.