# C++ substring multi byte characters

Tags: c++, character-encoding, wstring

I am having this std::string which contains some characters that span multiple bytes.

When I do a substring on this string, the output is not valid, because ofcourse, these characters are counted as 2 characters. In my opinion I should be using a wstring instead, because it will store these characters in as one element instead of more.

So I decided to copy the string into a wstring, but ofcourse this does not make sense, because the characters remain split over 2 characters. This only makes it worse.

Is there a good solution on converting a string to a wstring, merging the special characters into 1 element instead of 2.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4804298/1158895

Comment: what's the encoding of your string ? I assume UTF-8

Comment: @SirDarius, UTF-8 indeed. But I think this question could serve for any encoding taking multiple bytes for one character, no?

Comment: of course, but it is important to know, because some encodings require wide strings with characters as large as 32 bits. You might want to use a library such as libiconv.

Comment: @W.Goeman: One important issue: `std::wstring` is **unfortunately** implementation dependent (16 bits wide characters on Windows, 32 bits wide on Linux), therefore it is *not* sufficient.

Comment: "_UTF-8 indeed_" in NFC or in NFD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really only two possible solutions.  If you're doing this a
lot, over large distances, you'd be better off converting your
characters to a single element encoding, using `wchar_t` (or `int32_t`,
or whatever is most appropriate.  This is *not* a simple copy, which
would convert each individual `char` into the target type, but a true
conversion function, which would recognize the multibyte characters, and
convert them into a single element.

For occasional use or shorter sequences, it's possible to write your own
functions for advancing `n` bytes.  For UTF-8, I use the following:

```
inline size_t
size(
    Byte                ch )
{
    return byteCountTable[ ch ] ;
}

template< typename InputIterator >
InputIterator
succ(
    InputIterator       begin,
    size_t              size,
    std::random_access_iterator_tag )
{
    return begin + size ;
}

template< typename InputIterator >
InputIterator
succ(
    InputIterator       begin,
    size_t              size,
    std::input_iterator_tag )
{
    while ( size != 0 ) {
        ++ begin ;
        -- size ;
    }
    return begin ;
}

template< typename InputIterator >
InputIterator
succ(
    InputIterator       begin,
    InputIterator       end )
{
    if ( begin != end ) {
        begin = succ( begin, end, size( *begin ),
                      std::::iterator_traits< InputIterator >::iterator_category() ) ;
    }
    return begin ;
}

template< typename InputIterator >
size_t
characterCount(
    InputIterator       begin,
    InputIterator       end )
{
    size_t              result = 0 ;
    while ( begin != end ) {
        ++ result ;
        begin = succ( begin, end ) ;
    }
    return result ;
}
```

Comment: It should be noticed that `wchar_t` is only 16-bit on many platforms, so it's incapable of representing many codepoints in only a single element. Instead, `char32_t` is a type provided by C++11 that is fixed-width and sufficient to represent all of Unicode in a single element.

Answer (score 7):

Simpler version.
based on the solution provided [Getting the actual length of a UTF-8 encoded std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063146/getting-the-actual-length-of-a-utf-8-encoded-stdstring) by Marcelo Cantos

```
std::string substr(std::string originalString, int maxLength)
{
    std::string resultString = originalString;

    int len = 0;
    int byteCount = 0;

    const char* aStr = originalString.c_str();

    while(*aStr)
    {
        if( (*aStr & 0xc0) != 0x80 )
            len += 1;

        if(len>maxLength)
        {
            resultString = resultString.substr(0, byteCount);
            break;
        }
        byteCount++;
        aStr++;
    }

    return resultString;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is only partially correct. If you look at my answer you will see that you are successfully taking care of 1. (not cutting in the middle of a codepoint) however you are failing at 2. (not separating a codepoint from its diacritics) and 3. (not cutting in the middle of a semantic character, such as LL in Spanish). The latter two are rarer cases, certainly, but... well, dealing correctly with edge cases is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

A [`std::string`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html) object is not a string of characters, it's a string of bytes. It has no notion of what's called "[encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)" at all. Same goes for [`std::wstring`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html), except that it's a string of 16bit values.

In order to perform operations on your text which require addressing distinct characters (as is the case when you want to take the substring, for instance) you need to know what encoding is used for your std::string object.

**UPDATE:** Now that you clarified that your input string is UTF-8 encoded, you still need to decide on an encoding to use for your output `std::wstring`. UTF-16 comes to mind, but it really depends on what the API which you will pass the `std::wstring` objects to expect. Assuming that UTF-16 is acceptable you have various choices:

1. On Windows, you can use the [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function; no extra dependencies required.
2. The [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) library claims to provide a lightweight solution for dealing with UTF-* encoded strings. Never tried it myself, but I keep hearing good things about it.
3. On Linux systems, using the [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) library is quite common.
4. If you need to deal with all sorts of crazy encodings and want the full-blown alpha-and-omega word as far as encodings go, look at [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: `std::wstring` is a string of `wchar_t` which _may_ be 16 bits, _or_ 32 bits.

Comment: I am aware of that, and I do know my encoding. The question is how to do the transformation using that encoding.

Comment: @W.Goeman: I now updated my answer with some suggestions how to convert UTF-8 to some other encoding (even with `std::wstring` you still need to make up your mind what encoding to use).

Answer (score 1):

**Unicode is hard.**

1. `std::wstring` is not a list of codepoints, it's a list of `wchar_t`, and their width is implementation-defined (commonly 16 bits with VC++ and 32 bits with gcc and clang). Yes, it means it's useless for portable code...
2. A single character may be encoded on several code points (because of [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic))
3. In some language, two different characters together form a "unit" that is not really separable (for example, `LL` is considered a letter on its own in Spanish).

So... it's a bit hard.

Solving 3) may be costly (it requires specific language/usage annotations); solving 1) and 2) is absolutely necessary... and requires Unicode aware libraries or coding your own (and probably getting it wrong).

- 1) is trivially solved: writing a routine transforming from UTF-8 to CodePoint is trivial (a CodePoint can be represented with an `uint32_t`)
- 2) is more difficult, it requires a list of diacritics and the sub routine must know never to cut prior to a diacritic (they follow the character they qualify)

Otherwise, there is probably what you seek in [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). I wish you good luck finding it.

Comment: Unicode is not hard if your language comes with a decent standard libary. C++ doesn't have such. Also, LL is not a letter in Spanish; it used to be considered such due to some Royal Academy stupidity but they finally admitted it's a digraph and for quite some time it hasn't been considered a letter in academia, textbooks, Spanish locales, and so on. The confusion came from Spanish letters being so close to phonemes, and LL and CH being used to represent different phonemes.

Comment: @MiguelPérez: Ah glad to know, I learned Spanish a few years ago and the dictionary confused me a lot because of that weirdness. Unfortunately it is not the only language where this occurs ;)

Comment: "_diacritic (they **follow** the character they qualify)_" what is the proper name for this? Masochism?

Comment: @curiousguy: whether following or preceding, I do not think it would be any better. And it does avoid the combinatorial explosion of possibilities... and make our life really difficult :(

Comment: What I mean is: with prefixing, is you read a diacritic, you know it must be followed by another code point, and you have to consume one more code point. But with postfixing, if you read a letter, you do know not anything. It could be a letter alone, or it could combine with the following diacritic: you have to look at the next code point, just in case (how can you even do that on blocking streams?).

Comment: If the following code point is not a diacritic, you have to it back in some buffer.  With `istream` you can use `unget()` (`sungetc()` for `streambuf`, but it only works if an "input sequence putback position" is available, I don't remember when if it is ever guaranteed), for a Unix file (tty, TCP, pipe...), you have ... nothing AFAIK.

Comment: @curiousguy: with `istream` you can `peek` at the next character without taking it out :) I do agree though that in hindsight prefixing would have been better.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-05-faster-utf8-strlen.html) I've written my utf8 substring function:

```
void utf8substr(std::string originalString, int SubStrLength, std::string& csSubstring)
{
    int len = 0, byteIndex = 0;
    const char* aStr = originalString.c_str();
    size_t origSize = originalString.size();

    for (byteIndex=0; byteIndex < origSize; byteIndex++)
    {
        if((aStr[byteIndex] & 0xc0) != 0x80)
            len += 1;

        if(len >= SubStrLength)
            break;
    }

    csSubstring = originalString.substr(0, byteIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume for simplicity that your encoding is UTF-8. In this case we would have some chars occupying more than one byte, as in your case. 
Then you have std::string, where those UTF-8 encoded characters are stored. 
And now you want to substr() in terms of chars, not bytes. 
I'd write a function that will convert character length to byte length. For the utf 8 case it would look like:

```
#define UTF8_CHAR_LEN( byte ) (( 0xE5000000 >> (( byte >> 3 ) & 0x1e )) & 3 ) + 1

int32 GetByteCountForCharCount(const char* utf8Str, int charCnt)
{
    int ByteCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < charCnt; i++)
    {
        int charlen = UTF8_CHAR_LEN(*utf8Str);
        ByteCount += charlen;
        utf8Str += charlen;
    }
    return ByteCount;
}
```

So, say you want to substr() the string from 7-th char. No problem:

```
int32 pos = GetByteCountForCharCount(str.c_str(), 7);
str.substr(pos);
```

Comment: Why oh why using a macro instead of an inline function ? Why oh why passing a `char const*` instead of a `std::string const&`. Please, use C++ idioms in C++ questions.