# Writing data to serial port, sends wrong character

Tags: java, serial-port, jssc

When monitoring data sent to device i get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0kIT.png

but i expect one character: F0        ð

```java
 public void WritingDataToPort() {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM26");
        try {
            System.out.println(port.openPort());
            port.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
            port.writeString((char)240+""));
            port.closePort();
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
 }
```

I completly don't know how to send this "ð" characater. Tried all ascii codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just send the char (or UTF8) through the serial port. You have to convert it.
First get the length of the char in UTF-8, then get the bytes and send the bytes.

Getting the size of UTF-8: [Getting the actual length of a UTF-8 encoded std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063146/getting-the-actual-length-of-a-utf-8-encoded-stdstring)

Then send it one by one. On the other side you need something to assemble them back.

You could also consider using a better alternative to writing bytes directly to the port, such as http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/

Comment: Works only using method writeIntArray. Tried C/C++/Java source code  "\u00F0" but doesn't work. Thanks I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try unicode. UTF-8 code.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f0/index.htm

```
C/C++/Java source code  "\u00F0"
```