# Getting the correct length of string with special character

Tags: c++

The following code returns 3:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "€";
    return str.length();
}
```

I want it to return 1. It returns 3 because the euro symbol is represented by "\342\202\254". I need it to return 1 to align some text in columns.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063146/getting-the-actual-length-of-a-utf-8-encoded-stdstring

Comment: That solves it. Thank you.